# How to read the file line by line having matching string into list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to read a given file line by line and print the lines with matching string and append them into a list.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `with open(file_name) as f: \n   your_list=[line for line in f if your_word in line]`

Answer (score 0):

Reading a file line-by-line in an efficent way can be doen using the "with" statment:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
   for line in f:
      if line in wordlist:
          //do something
```

the with statement ensure that the opened resources (the file in this case) will be closed.
iterating over line with a for loop is readable and simple.

Comment: `if line in wordlist:` likely is wrong since that sounds like comparing a string of words to a list of words. More likely to be something like `if any(word in line for word in wordlist):` if there is a list words to compare against a string of words.  Or you could use set arithmetic to compare a set of the words in line to a set of the words to look for...

Answer (score 0):

```
    content = []
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_name):
         for file in files:
            name = os.path.join(path,file)
            print (name)
            data = open(name,"r")
            for line in data:
            if re.match("(.*)TOTAL(.*)",line):
                content.append(line)
    print(content)
```